# R: Confused about robust standard errors using “felm” and “huxreg”

Tags: r, regression, robust-standard-error

I’m working on panel data and want to use a *“least squares dummy variable”* (LSDV) approach, aka using factors to control for fixed effects rather than “within” differences.

I use a large set of indicators (many factor levels), so that normal OLS is relatively slow and the regression output is ugly. Therefore I explored the R-package `lfe`. It provides the function `felm` which “absorbs” factors (similar to Stats’s `areg`).

I need to use robust standard errors (HC1 or so) since tests indicate that there might be heteroscedasticity.

This is not so flamboyant after all. However, I obtain odd results for the robust SEs (using `felm` and `huxreg`).

**Here is an example:**

```
library(sandwich) # for robust SEs
library(lmtest)
library(huxtable) # for tables
library(lfe)      # "absorbe" FE Dummies with "felm"
library(ISLR)     # Auto data
library(jtools)   # for exporting summary
```

**I) Let's compare `felm` and `lm`:**

```
fe1 = felm(mpg~+cylinders+displacement | as.factor(year), data=Auto)
fe2 = lm(mpg~+cylinders+displacement + as.factor(year), data=Auto)
huxreg(fe1,fe2)
```

Output:

```
───────────────────────────────────────────────────
                          (1)            (2)       
                    ───────────────────────────────
  cylinders            -0.297          -0.297      
                       (0.359)         (0.359)     
  displacement         -0.045 ***      -0.045 ***  
                       (0.006)         (0.006)     
  (Intercept)                          32.401 ***
```

So `felm` and `lm` yield the same results, just as expected.

As stated in the `felm` docs (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lfe/versions/2.8-2/topics/felm), we can get robust SEs by calling:

```
summary(fe1, robust=T)
```

This is what I get:

```
Coefficients:
              Estimate Robust s.e t value Pr(>|t|)    
cylinders    -0.296565   0.350533  -0.846    0.398    
displacement -0.045153   0.005994  -7.533  3.7e-13 ***
```

**II) Let's get robust SEs:**

Usually when I want to have robust SEs, I do something like this:

```
fe1_ro1 <- coeftest(fe1, vcov = vcovHC(fe1, type="HC1"))
fe2_ro1 <- coeftest(fe2, vcov = vcovHC(fe2, type="HC1"))
huxreg(fe1_ro1, fe2_ro1, number_format=6)
```

Output:

```
──────────────────────────────────────────────────
                         (1)            (2)       
                    ──────────────────────────────
  cylinders           -0.296565    -0.296565      
                      (4.593215)   (0.350533)     
  displacement        -0.045153    -0.045153 ***  
                      (0.078539)   (0.005994)     
  (Intercept)                      32.400736 ***
```

Consider the (robust) SEs of `displacement`:

1. From `summary(fe1, robust=T)` = 0.005994,
2. From `huxreg()` using `felm`  = 0.078539,
3. From `huxreg()` using `lm`    = 0.005994.

I think 0.005994 is correct, but I cannot work out from where the other value (0.07) comes!

**III) Try to pass summary() into regression table:**

It appears that `felm` got the robust SEs right when using `summary(fe1, robust=T)`. So I try to pass this result into a proper regression table.

I try `export_summs()` from `jtools` (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/jtools/versions/1.1.1/topics/export_summs):

```
export_summs(fe1, fe2, model.names = c("felm","lm"), robust = TRUE, number_format=6)
```

Output:

```
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                                                             felm                                       lm                     
                                          ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
  cylinders                                                           -0.296565                                 -0.296565      
                                                                      (0.358947)                                (0.359817)     
  displacement                                                        -0.045153 ***                             -0.045153 ***  
                                                                      (0.005891)                                (0.006158)     
  (Intercept)                                                                                                   32.400736 ***
```

It turnes out that the SEs for `displacement` using `lm` in the table above (0.006158) correspond to HC3 errors.

```
coeftest(fe2, vcov = vcovHC(fe2, type="HC3"))
```

So far, so good.

However, the SEs for `displacement` using `felm` (0.005891) are again different, and I do not see where they come from.

(Trying `coeftest(fe1, vcov = vcovHC(fe1, type="HC3"))` yields an error `Error in 1 - diaghat : non-numeric argument to binary operator`)

**IV) So here are my questions:**

- My stance is that robust SEs should be the same under `felm` and
  `lm`. Is this correct or do I miss some important argument here?
- If correct: How can I display correct robust SEs from `felm` in a
  proper (publication ready) regression table (in MS Word format) similar to `huxreg`?
- Finally and probably most important to me: Is there any alternative
  to `felm` (in `R`), viz. a command which allows to “absorb” a larger
  set of indicator variables to make LSDV workable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

1. The result from huxreg comes directly from the coeftest object:

```
> fe1_ro1

t test of coefficients:

              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
cylinders    -0.296565   4.593215 -0.0646   0.9486
displacement -0.045153   0.078539 -0.5749   0.5657
```

So the question is why `coeftest` is giving one result, and `summary.felm` another. The felm documentation doesn't say how exactly it calculates robust SEs; you might need to check the code or contact the author. I wouldn't assume that `summary.felm` is correct and `coeftest` is wrong (even if `summary.felm` gives significant results ;-) ). They may both be "right" but using different methods.

2. `huxreg` uses the `tidy` method from the `broom` package to get standard errors. `felm` has such a method but I don't think that `summary.felm` does. You can get round this by using the `tidy_override` function in recent huxtable.
3. You might look at `biglm` or `speedglm` for increasing OLS speed, though I don't think they specifically deal with LSDV issues. Another option would be `plm`, designed for panel data but perhaps useful for you.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old thread, but I wanted to clarify some issues in case anyone stumbles upon it.

*First an aside: You'd be much better off posting a question about R and R packages on StackOverflow than StackExchange.*

1. `lfe::felm()` has its own idiomatic way of calculating robust (and clustered) standard errors; more on this below. You should use that instead of trying to pass it through `lmtest::coeftest()`, which does not provide a method for handling felm objects. It might seem like it's working because the code executes (at least, sometimes), but the `coeftest()` documentation makes it pretty clear that it is intended for specific objects.
2. Okay, so how to report robust SEs from felm models in a regression table? As the OP correctly states, huxtable uses `broom::tidy()` underneath the hood. The latest version of broom ([v0.7.1](https://github.com/tidymodels/broom/releases/tag/v.0.7.1) at the time of writing) actually includes some bug fixes and and enhancements specific to felm objects. You can read the gory details [here](https://github.com/tidymodels/broom/pull/920) and the `?tidy.felm` help documentation provides a bunch of examples. The **TL;DR** version is to install the latest version of broom and then use the `se.type` argument.

Here's an example using the [modelsummary](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/index.html) package, which has similar functionality to huxreg, but I personally find a easier to control output and customization.

```
library(lmtest)
library(sandwich)
library(lfe)
library(ISLR)         ## Auto data
library(modelsummary) ## NB: make sure you've updated to broom>=v.0.7.1 first

fe1 = felm(mpg ~ cylinders + displacement | as.factor(year), data=Auto)
fe2 = lm(mpg ~ cylinders + displacement + as.factor(year), data=Auto)

mods = list(fe1, coeftest(fe2, vcov = vcovHC(fe2, type="HC1")))

msummary(
    mods, 
    output = 'table.docx', ## Optional if saving to MS Word as OP requested
    se.type = 'robust'     ## Argument being passed to tidy.felm()
    )
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

[image]